# Running sum in vba, ms access

Tags: ms-access, sum, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to update one field (tblUSA.RunSum) with the running sum of another field (Length), starting at tblUSA.RunSum= 0 for the first value. So far, I'm having no luck. Mo updates tblUSA are writing.

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
Dim lastValue, thisValue

s = "tblUSA"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(s, dbOpenDynaset)

'rs.Sort ("DateS")

lastValue = rs.Fields("Length")
rs.MoveNext

While (Not rs.EOF())
        thisValue = rs.Fields("Length")
        rs.Edit
           rs!RunSum = thisValue + lastValue
        rs.Update
        lastValue = thisValue ' remember previous value
        rs.MoveNext           ' advance to next record
Wend

MsgBox "Done with " & s
```

Comment: Should last value not be `rs.Fields("RunSum")` as the length isn't a running total.

Comment: Thanks much!  I changed that, and still no luck

Comment: how many records in your table ? Does it have a unique value which dictates the Running sum order ?

Comment: Yes, the date field - called DateS.  There are about 500 records.

Answer (score 0):

This might do:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim lastValue As Double
Dim s As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
s = "Select * From tblUSA Order By DateS"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(s, dbOpenDynaset)

While Not rs.EOF
    rs.Edit
       rs!RunSum.Value = lastValue   ' Initially = 0
    rs.Update
    lastValue = lastValue + rs.Fields("Length").Value
    rs.MoveNext 
Wend
rs.Close
```

Comment: Thanks, that *should* work, but there is some kind of row lock on the table that kicks in whenever this code runs...there is a circle with a slash through it on each row, and I can't edit the table

Comment: You cannot run this code while you are editing a record in the form.